# Change screen brightness in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change brightness of my screen when I'm opening some fragment which placed in my activity so I placed so code for this in onActivityCreated (I also tried to placed it onResume). But I want to return my screen to previous brightness when user is closing this fragment. But for now brightness applies for all activity. How to apply brittleness only for fragment? Or record brightness result and retrun it, when fragment is closed?

```
class BrightnessFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        appCompatActivity = activity as AppCompatActivity

        val lp = activity!!.window.attributes
        lp.screenBrightness = 1F
        activity!!.window.attributes = lp
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could store the previous brightness in a variable within the `Fragment`. When the `Fragment` is being removed, it will call `onDestroy()`, which is a good time to reset the brightness.

And as a side note, when you're writing in Kotlin, try to refrain from using `!!`. You should handle the case gracefully if it's null. With a `?.let`, you can write it so it will only change the brightness if the `Activity` is not null (`it` is the `Activity` in this case).

```
class BrightnessFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {

    companion object {
        // Using a constant to make the code cleaner.
        private const val MAX_BRIGHTNESS = 1F
    }

    // Our stored previous brightness.
    private var previousBrightness = MAX_BRIGHTNESS

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.let {
            val attributes = it.window.attributes

            // Store the previous brightness
            previousBrightness = attributes.screenBrightness

            // Set the brightness to MAX_BRIGHTNESS.
            attributes.screenBrightness = MAX_BRIGHTNESS
            it.window.attributes = attributes
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.let {
            val attributes = it.window.attributes

            // Set the brightness to previousBrightness.
            attributes.screenBrightness = previousBrightness
            it.window.attributes = attributes
        }
        // Don't forget to called super.onDestroy()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the !! note

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw, why did you have to use `(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.let` instead of simply using `activity?.let`